# In R, how can we change variables dynamically in a specified linear model, which are of different type (factorial, numeric)?

Tags: r, dynamic, lm

In R, I am trying to change the variables inside my linear model dynamically. I have saved a character vector of variables that I want to use in my lm as moderating variables. This works well for numeric type of variables, however, it is not a good solution for the factor type variables as R does not know they are factors with levels.

My problem is outlined below with a simple example, say I have some data here...

```
yVar <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
xVar <- c(2,1,2,1,2)
numVar1 <- c(1,2,2,3,4)
numVar2 <- c(1,1,2,2,3)
facVar1 <-c(1,2,3,4,5)
facVar2 <-c(1,2,1,2,1) 

xVar <- factor(xVar,levels=c(1:2),labels=c("Condition1","Condition2"))
facVar1 <-factor(facVar1,levels=c(1:5),labels=c("red","blue","green","black","yellow"))
facVar2 <-factor(facVar2, levels=c(1:2), labels=c("dog","cat"))

studyData <- data.frame(yVar,xVar,numVar1,numVar2,facVar1,facVar2)
```

The standard model would look like:

```
standardModel <- lm(data=studyData, yVar ~ xVar)
summary.aov(standardModel)
```

I would like to dynamically include a list of moderating variables to use with this model from zList. As so:

```
zList <- c("numVar1","numVar2","facVar1","facVar2")
```

And then call variables from the Z list

```
for (z in zList) {
  lmfit <- lm(as.formula(paste("yVar ~ xVar*",z)), data=studyData)
  print(z)
  print(typeof(z))
  print(levels(z))
  print(summary.aov(lmfit))
}
```

This gives the output below:

```
[1] "numVar1"
[1] "character"
NULL
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
xVar          1  0.000   0.000   0.000  1.000
numVar1       1  9.484   9.484  33.194  0.109
xVar:numVar1  1  0.230   0.230   0.806  0.534
Residuals     1  0.286   0.286               
[1] "numVar2"
[1] "character"
NULL
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq   F value Pr(>F)    
xVar          1      0       0 2.200e-02  0.906    
numVar2       1     10      10 1.781e+31 <2e-16 ***
xVar:numVar2  1      0       0 7.560e-01  0.544    
Residuals     1      0       0                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
[1] "facVar1"
[1] "character"
NULL
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
xVar         1      0   0.000
facVar1      3     10   3.333
[1] "facVar2"
[1] "character"
NULL
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
xVar         1      0   0.000       0      1
Residuals    3     10   3.333
```

As can be seen, for the numeric type of variables, this solution seems to work (the no. of levels in NULL as they should be and the lm output looks fine). However, for factorial variables, the number of levels is also "NULL", so R doesn't know that this variable is of type factor and has levels.

What could I do so that I could run my linear model, and allow variables to change dynamically on the fly, whereby R knows what type the variable is? Is there an alternative better way of solving this problem?

Thank you in advance for any replies.

Comment: `z` is a character string, the variable can be accessed with `get(z)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the loop to print the information about `z` while it is fitting the several models, the following code will do it. The vector `zList` is a character vector, so `z` is a character string, the variables can be accessed with `get(z)`.

The fitted models will be in list `lm_list`. Then a sequence of simpler `lapply` instructions can produce `aov` objects (in a list, `aov_list`) or summary statistics.

```
lm_list <- lapply(zList, function(z) {
  cat("\n", "name:", z, "\n")
  zvar <- get(z)
  cat("typeof:", typeof(zvar), "\n")
  cat("class:", class(zvar), "\n")
  if(is.factor(zvar)) cat("levels:", levels(zvar), "\n")
  fmla <- as.formula(paste("yVar ~ xVar *", z))
  lm(fmla, data = studyData)
})

lm_smry <- lapply(lm_list, summary)
lm_smry

aov_list <- lapply(lm_list, aov)
lapply(aov_list, summary)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, running the lm model with the z variable included, whether this z variable is factorial or numeric, is what I am looking for. Is it possible to write the loop differently using get(), so this information can be referenced from the data frame, and then used in the lm?

Comment: @JoeyyyFunk  Done, see now.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful! Minor question, I wondered how it's possible to print some basic text with each iteration of the lapply? For example printing y="yVar" or mod="zvar". Just for tidy house keeping purposes and labelling of the model summaries for sharing with others. Thanks again.

Comment: @JoeyyyFunk If you assign `names(lm_list) <- zList` right after the models are created, then `lm_smry <- lapply(lm_list, summary)` will put the names in `lm_smry`. Is this it?

Comment: Yes that's it! Thanks very much for all your help .